# How can I make my paladin alive again without his whole body?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, resurrection, helping

Our party (gunslinger 13 lvl, wizard universalist 12 lvl & paladin 13 lvl) were in the dungeon (Runeforge, "Rise of the Runelords). The gunslinger became dominated and killed the paladin (his head exploded). We can't go outside, and can't teleport anywhere (constant dimensional anchor). All we've got is our wizard and scroll of limited wish. We need our paladin back, but the *Raise Dead* spell needs the whole body. What can we do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 24):

One option is to use the Limited Wish to cast [Reincarnate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/), which creates a new body. Granted, you *might* be getting back a Paladin that looks different from the original, but at least he'll be back alive.

Comment: My character died and got reincarnated in Rise of the Runelords as well, but I got lucky with the reincarnation, changed only from human to half elf. :)

Answer (score 15):

If a corpse is considered an item by your DM (I've seen it go either way) you might be permitted to use Mending on the corpse with the collected Head Bits prior to a Raise Dead.

Comment: Mending probably isn't even strictly necessary.  If it'll repair organs crushed to pulp by a warhammer it'll repair a pulped head if you just mush it back together a bit.  As a DM I'd probably call for search checks to find all the bits or risk the paladin coming back missing an eye or an ear or a nose. (the description only mentions repairing lethal damage. He might well come back looking like Jigsaw with intelligence, charisma, and wisdom scores of 1 from the brain damage.)